# Como criar duas classes com mesmos métodos, mesmo uma delas não sendo `Partial`?

Tags: .net, vb.net, console

Posso criar uma classe para extender a classe `System.Console`, sem criar extensões?

Exemplo:

```
'A declaração original
Public NotInheritable Class Console
    ' ...
End Class
```

Ela está marcada como uma classe não partial, então... não dá para simplesmente:

```
Partial Public NotInheritable Class Console
    ' .....
End Class
```

**Extensões não funcionam** porque ela é `NotInheritable`.

Se eu tentar fazer um clone dela? Como por exemplo:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Console
    Public Sub WriteLine(ByVal arg As String)
        System.Console.WriteLine(arg) ' Irá dar uma stack overflow...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Como posso fazer então duas classes Console? Mantendo os métodos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está confundindo alguns conceitos aqui. A classe estar declarada como `NotInheritable` significa que nenhuma classe pode herdar dela (`abstract` no C#). Herança é um conceito básico da Programação Orientada a Objetos e é bem mais amplo do que uma extensão.

**Partial Classes** é um recurso do .NET Framework e nada mais é do que a separação da mesma classe em mais de um arquivo. No final das contas você tem apenas uma classe, com membros divididos logicamente. Isso é muito útil em aplicações baseadas em eventos, como Windows Form e ASP.NET WebForms, onde os controles são declarados em um arquivo e a lógica da manipulação da interface de usuário em outro, mas ambos são a mesma classe.

Quanto a sua pergunta não é possível "extender" uma classe dessa maneira, mas se quiser criar um clone é possível utilizando outro `namespace`:

```
Namespace Sistema
    Public Class Console
        Public Shared Sub WriteLine(ByVal arg As String)
            System.Console.WriteLine(arg)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Então pode usá-la assim:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Sistema.Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
    End Sub
End Module
```

### OU

Se você quer realmente sobrepor os métodos do `System`, então deve remover as referências dele do projeto. Crie uma aplicação console e remova todas as referências (nas propriedades do projeto):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Defina o `namespace` raíz como `System`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E daí o código. Tenha em mente que dessa maneira todas as funcionalidades do `System` foram perdidas, você terá que realmente reescrevê-las:

```
Public Class Console
    Public Shared Sub WriteLine(ByVal arg As String)
        ' código da sua implementação de escrita no console
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: É, não era isso que queria, estou tentando criar um módulo para entrar no lugar da classe `System.Console`, usando libs do Win32Native. porém não ta dando certo, da dando `Ambigous`.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta, veja se entende e te atende.

Comment: Funcionou, porém, se algum aplicativo for usar minha assembly, irá ter que remover uma das referências para usar a minha referência....

Comment: Exatamente, mas é algo quer faz todo sentido, já que você está reescrevendo o namespace.

Comment: Sim, to criando um projeto de expansão para a namespace System, e quero colocar um método na classe "Console", não consigo usar extensões, ta difícil...